# Differential operators as Laplacians

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Given a (second order elliptic) differential operator $D$ on a manifold, when can it be realized as $D=-\Delta + v$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace - Beltrami operator of a Riemannian metric, and $v$ is a vector field? If $D$ is symmetric with respect to a smooth measure $\rho$, can it be realized as $D=-\Delta$ for a Riemannian metric whose Riemannian volume is $\rho$? I was certain that it must be covered in textbooks, but couldn't find any references.